# What is the difference between a "procedure name IS' and a "Procedure name AS" in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql-package

> PROCEDURE sample   (p_num1   IN TABLE%TYPE,
>                         p_num2   OUT NUMBER) IS

**OR**

> PROCEDURE sample   (p_num1   IN TABLE%TYPE,
>                         p_num2   OUT NUMBER) AS

Comment: There's no difference. Use the one you like most.

Comment: If you're ever unsure, look up the documentation. For `CREATE PROCEDURE`, you can see that IS and AS are interchangeable. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is only one letter: `I` vs. `A`. You can use both, there won't be any *other* difference. The effect of executing both is the same except for the same minor difference stored in the data dictionary tables [CDB|DBA|ALL|USER]_SOURCE.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is begin null; end;
  2  /

Procedure created.

    SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as begin null; end;
      2  /

    Procedure created.

    SQL>
```

Note that it doesn't work for e.g. views:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as select * from emp;

View created.

SQL> create or replace view v_emp is select * from emp;
create or replace view v_emp is select * from emp
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```